# About assertion and abort trap 6

Tags: c, debugging

This is a program that main used to for money-exchange calculation. But the problem here is that when i compile it and run, it said

Assertion failed: (argc ==4 || argc == 2), function main, file test.c, line 24.
Abort trap: 6

Thanks!!!!

```
void convert(int type, double amount, double rate);

int get_type(char* string);

void convert(int type, double amount, double rate) {
    printf("%.2f %s is %.2f %s\n", amount, type == 1 ? "dollars" : "euros", amount * rate, type == 1 ? "euros" : "dollars");
}

int get_type(char* string) {
    int i, c;
    for (i = 0, c = string[0]; c != '\0'; c = string[i]) {
            if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
                    string[i] -= 'A' - 'a';
            }
    }
    return !strcmp(string, "dollar") ? 1 : !strcmp(string, "euro") ? 2 : 0;
}   

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    assert(argc ==4 || argc == 2);
    if (argc == 4) {
            int type = get_type(argv[1]);
            if (type == 0) {
                    printf("%s is an invalid currency type. Use dollar or euro.\n", argv[1]);
                    return 1;
            }
            convert(type, atof(argv[2]), atof(argv[3]));
    }

    if (argc == 2) {
            FILE* fd;
            fd = fopen(argv[1], "r");
            if (fd == NULL) {
                    printf("Could not open %s\n", argv[1]);
                    return 1;
            }
            char* typestring = (char*)malloc(16 * sizeof(char));
            double amount, rate;
int matches, type;

            while (!feof(fd)) {
                    matches = fscanf(fd, "%s %lf %lf\n", typestring, &amount, &rate);
                    if (matches != 3) {
                            printf("Line was not formed correctly.\n");
                            continue;
                    }
                    type = get_type(typestring);
                    if (type == 0) {
                            printf("%s is an invalid currency type. Use dollar or euro.\n", typestring);
                            continue;
                    }
                    convert(type, amount, rate);
            }
            free(typestring);
    }


    if (argc == 2 && argc != 4) {
            printf("Usage:\n\tmoney-exchange [dollar|euro type] [double amount] [double rate]\n");
            printf("\tmoney-exchange [FILE]\n");
            printf("Examples:\n\tmoney-exchange dollar 10.50 0.92\n");
            printf("\tmoney-exchange euro 5.99 1.09\n");
            printf("\tmoney-exchange prices.txt\n");
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not providing the correct number of arguments for your program when you run it. You have to either provide one or three arguments (the extra one being the command itself, of course).

In other words, you should run it as something like:

```
money-exchange inputfile.txt
```

or:

```
money-exchange dollar 42 0.9
```

---

As an aside, I'm not really a big fan of using `assert` for this by the way, since they're typically disabled in production code. Better would be for the code to simply check `argc` and exit with an error message itself. That way, you can be certain it's checked in all cases:

```
if ((argc != 2) && (argc != 4)) {
    fprintf (stderr, "What the heck are you thinking?");
    return 1;
}
```

Doubly so in this case since you actually *have* code that will do exactly this but the `assert` is exiting the program before it gets to that point, preventing it from showing the usage details if you call it wrongly.

I would ditch the `assert`, it's not giving you any protection beyond what you already have with the `argc` checking.